# how to set culture and uiculture to specific CultureInfo

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm trying to create a middleware that hard codes the Culture and UICulture based on a value in the config file.

I get the value from config (either nb-NO or en-US) and creates a CultureInfo object. But the site is using en-US even when set to nb-NO.

**Middleware**:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    CultureInfo cult = new CultureInfo(_config["Culture"]);

    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = cult;
    CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = cult;

    await _next.Invoke(context);
}
```

This is from a tutorial from MS, can I set Culture and UICulture some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by moving the UseMiddleware line under the configuration for localization

Answer (score 0):

**DefaultThreadCurrentCulture**

> Gets or sets the default culture for threads in the current
>   application domain.

[for more info look at here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture?view=netframework-4.8)

```
  CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(_config["Culture"]);
```